# Can I run an instance of macOS Catalina in my Windows 10 Docker Desktop

Tags: macos-catalina, docker-for-windows

I'm a developer I'm trying to validate my MS Office VBA applications across multiple environments. I was told that some users have macOS Catalina installed.

My current plan prior to this information was to use Docker Desktop to spin up multiple instances of various environments to test compatibility with my application.

Using Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 machine, can you launch an instance of macOS Catalina?

Comment: Not within terms of Apple's EULA, no.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: Given I don't believe you can run Windows within a Docker container, even if you could run macOS within a Docker container, it would have to be done on Apple hardware.  You can of course run macOS within a VM, and that is the case for both. VMWare and VirtualBox VMs on Apple hardware.  [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/607443/can-mac-os-x-be-run-inside-docker) Server Fault question explains the reasons OS X cannot be ran within an Docker container.  **Given the Hackintosh element of this question I won't be submitting an answer that provides a summary of that answer.**

Comment: Thank you for letting me know of the issue with Apple products being run on non-Apple hardware.